# DAX code to count orders with crossed categories

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I've got a list of units which are being sold by a shop. Each line describes date, order number, number of units and category (A and B in this example).

How can I, using just DAX measures in a pivot table, know how many orders are both in categories A and B per day? I've tried using CALCULATE in several ways, but I can't find the correct way to do it...

In this link I show you a screenshot of a sample table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIGmz.jpg)

The pivot table should show:

```
25/05/2016  3 (orders 100, 104 and 105 have units from categories A and B)  
26/05/2016  1 (order 200 has units from categories A and B)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure that counts the distinct OrderNo. The just create your pivot table and use that measure. You can use two expressions for the measure.

Excel 2010:

```
=COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(TableName[OrderNo]))
```

Excel 2013+

```
=DISTINCTCOUNT(TableName[OrderNo])
```

With the measure created in your model create a pivot table. Drag and drop `Date` field to rows, `Category` field to columns and the created measure to `Values`.

You will get something like this:

[image]

Ignore the labels excel put to the pivot table, my OS language setting is Spanish.

---

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment, you need the distinct OrderNo's that have Categories A and B.

Use the following expression:

```
=CALCULATE (
    COUNTA (TablaName[OrderNo]),
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( TablaName[OrderNo] ), TablaName[Category] = "A" ),
   TablaName[Category] = "B"
)
```

I was thinking of using intersect function which is not supported in Excel 2010 but this is a general way to get your expected result.

This is the pivot table generated from it.

[image]

Hopefully this is what you are looking for, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but maybe the question wasn't clear (I edited it with the data the pivot table should display). If I use DISTINCTCOUNT in this way I just get the orders with either A (column A) or column B (column B), but I'd like to get the number of orders having both A and B items.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column with the following formula:

> = if(
>   CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(mytable[Category]),filter(all(mytable),mytable[Date]=EARLIER(mytable[Date])&&mytable[OrderNo]=EARLIER(mytable[OrderNo])),or(mytable[Category]="A",mytable[Category]="B"))
>   =2,true(),false())
>   The earlier function compares rows with same date and orderNo.
>   The extra or filter, only takes into account the category A and B.

This will return true/false on orders with category A and B. 
Since you can't do a regular count, because you have multiple lines 
for a ordernr. You need a distinctcount.

new measure:

> =CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(mytable[OrderNo]),mytable[CalcColumn01]=true())